# My output not showing the full numbers but showing ?? instead

Tags: java, netbeans, benchmarking, jmh

I'm trying to do benchmarking with JMH, the benchmarking result did come out but not perfectly
[image]

Somehow there's ?? in the numbers, is it the problem with my IDE where I need to set up the settings to show the full numbers or something?

Comment: I think the first is supposed to be `±`, I'm not sure about the second and third. The character set of your console probably doesn't support it. Are you running on Windows?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I'm using windows.

Answer (score 1):

The JMH output makes use of extended Unicode characters. In particular, ? 10?? s/op" probably means "≈ 10⁻¹⁰ s/op".

To solve it

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class MyBenchmark {
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are facing is an encoding issue.

JMH by default encodes its output as  UTF-8 so instead of those `??` you'll see `±` for Error column and e.g. `≈ 10⁻³` for Score column on Linux or Mac.

On Windows Unicode is supported in terminal but not entirely, this is why you see `??` instead of some symbols. To fix this please follow the manual described in another SO question: [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line)